# SQL query retrieve every other rows with or without using IN

Tags: sql

In a standard SQL query, it is necessary to retrieve rows where the column id is equal to 2, 4, 6, and 8 in the item table. Give two ways in which these values can be searched for without using IN. Explain the pros and cons of each way.
Source: http://www.glassdoor.com/Interview/The-Zappos-Family-Software-Engineer-Interview-Questions-EI_IE19906.0,17_KO18,35_IP2.htm

Comment: This is not the homework hotline.

Comment: Sorry I will stop asking questions like this. It's just I have an interview tomorrow and I forgot SQL and found some problems to practice getting stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the mod operator on columnID assuming sequential assignment of the columnID, if not use ROW ID.  CON assumes an arbitrary order to the table exists and each row has to be evaluated adding to compute time.

use a where clause where mod(ColumnID,2) = 0.  again assumes sequential assignment of columnID but should be able to leverage an index whereas the prior example could leverage a function based index.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a modulo (%) in your condition to retrieve even id numbered rows. Mod gives you the remainder from a dividend and a divisor.

Something like:

```
...
WHERE id % 2 = 0;
```